# Rails 3: How to return a big JSON document

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to return about 90k items in a JSON document but I'm getting this error when I make the call:

```
Timeout::Error in ApisController#api_b

time's up!
Rails.root: /root/api_b
```

I am simply running "rails s" with the default rails server.

What's the way to make this work and return the document?

Thanks

```
  @bs.each do |a|
          puts "dentro do bs.each"
          @final << {  :Email => a['headers']['to'], :At => a['date'], :subject => a['headers']['subject'], :Type => a['headers']['status'], :Message_id => a['headers']['message_id'] }
        end
```

Being @bs the BSON object from MongoDB. The timeout is in "@final << ..."

Comment: What are the 90k items? Arrays, ActiveRecord records, Strings? I have dumped close to 9million LatLon arrays out of Rails 3 in json without a timeout.

Comment: It's 90k records from MongoDB. I get the BSON object and add it to a array using .each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are experiencing timeouts from rails and it is possible to cache the data (e.g. the data changes infrequently), I would generate the response in the background using [resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque#readme) or [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) and than have Rails dump that to the client. Or if the data cannot be cached, use a [lightweight Rack handler like Sinatra and Metal](http://railscasts.com/episodes/222-rack-in-rails-3) to generate the responses.

**Edited to reflect sample data**

I was able to run the following code in a Rails 3.0.9 instance against a high performance Mongo 1.8.4 instance. I was using Mongo 1.3.1, bson_ext 1.3.1, webrick 1.3.1 and Ruby 1.9.2p180 x64. It did not time out but it took some time to load.  My sample Mongo DB has 100k records and contains no indexes.

```
before_filter :profile_start
after_filter :profile_end
  def index
    db   = @conn['sample-dbs']
    collection = db['email-test']

    @final = []
    @bs = collection.find({})
    @bs.each do |a|
      puts "dentro do bs.each"
      @final << {  :Email => a['headers']['to'], :At => a['date'], :subject => a['headers']['subject'], :Type => a['headers']['status'], :Message_id => a['headers']['message_id'] }
    end
    render :json => @final
  end

  private
    def profile_start
      RubyProf.start
    end

    def profile_end
      RubyProf::FlatPrinter.new(RubyProf.stop).print
    end
```

A more efficient way to dump out the records would be

```
@bs = collection.find({}, {:fields => ["headers", "date"]})
@final = @bs.map{|a| {:Email => a['headers']['to'], :At => a['date'], :subject => a['headers']['subject'], :Type => a['headers']['status'], :Message_id => a['headers']['message_id'] }}
render :json => @final
```

My data generator

```
 100000.times do |i|
   p i
   @coll.insert({:date =>Time.now(),:headers => {"to"=>"me@foo.com", "subject"=>"meeeeeeeeee", "status" => "ffffffffffffffffff", "message_id" => "1234634673"}})
 end
```

Comment: I have exactl your first option, however, the 30 seconds timeout is here:   @final << {  :Email => a['headers']['to'], :At => a['date'], :subject => a['headers']['subject'], :Type => a['headers']['status'], :Message_id => a['headers']['message_id'] } After I retrieve the data from MongoDB and put it in an array.

Comment: I have the same code as you and only with 15k documents it gets timeout. Why could it be? Maybe because each object is bigger?

Comment: If it is because each object is bigger, you could try limiting to only pulling the fields you need from Mongo with `:fields => ["headers", "date"]`. I've edited to reflect your question.